# Add Custom Marker to Google Map with API v2

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'm attempting to add a custom marker to a Google Map using v2 of the API. However, I've been unsuccessful. The code I'm trying to use is found at [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Icons_overview). You'll find my work in progress at [My Map](http://cspc.net/resources/neighborhood-map). I appreciate any guidance you can provide. I simply want to drop a custom icon at (35.912075, -84.084563). Most of the support threads reference v3 of the API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V2 API has been deprecated and will be going away.  You should be using V3. I don't see any section in your code that references a custom marker.

Comment: Thanks, I now see support will be discontinued in 2013.